# Squash / fixup commits with merges

Tags: git, github

I have created branch AB from branch A, I have merged after some time new changes from A to AB, also have done some "work in progress" commits to AB;

Now I want to leave only one commit message with firs commit but to save there all data from merges and etc;

I have done `git log --pretty=oneline`

```
a last commit
b merge branch from A
c merge pull request from A
d meger branch from A
e WIP commit
f WIP commit
g WIP commit
h first commit
```

I am trying to do different combinations of `git rebase -i {commit}` but each time I am loosing some commits

How to do it in right way?

Comment: You can squash commits one by one (separate rebase runs). That one you can easily check the outcome after each step.

Comment: @arkascha trouble that merges are not showing in git-rebase-todo tool

Comment: You have the option --preserve-merges with git rebase --interactive, but as said in the doc, there are risks of bugs (see end of the page) : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: You mean you merged changes from A into commits in AB, besides those explicit merge commits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is with `git reset`. This command lets you keep all the contents as of the latest commit in your working directory, while moving your current branch to another commit. So do the following:

```
git branch backup        #keeps your current history from getting lost in case you screw up
git reset --soft h       #moves current branch to the first commit (i.e. h)
git commit --amend       #makes commit h contain all the changes you made
```

Once you verify all is as you want it, you can delete branch `backup`.

Comment: so nice; really very helpful!